# How big can zsh history get? How far back does it go?

Tags: configuration-files, zsh

I don't want to lose and command history. Does zsh_history ever truncate the file? If so, under what conditions? Also, do any other processes act upon it?

Comment: Type into terminal:> export HISTSIZE=10000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HISTSIZE` variable configures the size of the history file in *lines*. Make this big enough and you won't lose history.

See also `man zshparam` and search for `HISTSIZE` and `SAVEHIST`.

Comment: Ooo so "man something" is the terminal version of "something help" =)

Comment: That would be `apropos something` to give you a first iteration of a subsequent `man whatever`.